# Limit the drag cotrols of three.js scene to window

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have created a plane geometry and multiple objects using three.js. How to limit the drag control for plane geometry to the window (four sides). A plane geometry that should be limited to drag.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.

Comment: @msun How to limit pan or drag for a scene in three.js, right now i am able to drag anywhere there is no limitation. So i want to limit to Scene (four sides). Controls should be disabled when i reach the end of scene.